# AWS AppSync Lambda resolver $context.identity is null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to get the user's ip address in a lambda function called from AWS AppSync.

I tried with this input resolver:

```
{ 
    "version" : "2017-02-28", 
    "operation": "Invoke", 
    "payload": { 
         "arguments": $util.toJson($context.arguments),
         "sourceIp" : $context.identity.sourceIp 
    } 
}
```

But I found while testing that `$context.identity` is null when I call the function through the AppSync queries dashboard.

Are there other ways to get the user's ip address or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

**Update**:
With the help of aldarisbm, I came up with this input resolver:

```
#set ($forwardHeader = "${context.request.headers.X-Forwarded-For}")
#set ($comma = $forwardHeader.indexOf(','))
#set ($ip = $forwardHeader.substring(0, $comma))
#set ($payload = $context.arguments)
#set ($discard = $payload.put("sourceIp", "${ip}"))

{ "version" : "2017-02-28", "operation": "Invoke", "payload": $util.toJson($payload) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `$context.identity` specifically but have you tried checking the headers that AWS adds to your requests:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

There's a `X-Forwarded-For: client-ip-address`, header that gets added to requests.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: X-Forwarded-For can have more than 1 IP address https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html